# I can't seed a torrent without downloading it using transmission-daemon web interface

Tags: server, bittorrent, transmission

I am running Ubuntu server 20.04 on a Raspberry Pi 4, i seed a lot of torrents on my PC so i decided to install transmission-daemon on my rasp to have it working 24/7.
I wanted to transfer some of the torrents from my PC, so i copied the .torrent and the folders containing the material.
And when i open them the daemon start trying to download it (i am using the private tracker of a site).

What can i do to make the daemon recognise that i already have the files?
P.S. All of my torrents are folders, not single files and i am running transmission-daemon.service under "torrents" user, who have complete access to the download folder.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your question does not specify the interface that you are using: Shell/CLI, Web, GTK/QT, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your going to have to use the verify data option, this will force Transmission to compare the local data to that of the torrent. You said you were using the daemon so use something like this

````
"transmission-remote -t # -v" (where # is the torrent ID -- shown with "transmission-remote -l"); ```
````